# Why does my pygame game get slower over time?

Tags: python, pygame, frame-rate

I'm making a pygame project, but for some reason my game slows down slowly: after playing for a few minutes the fps is only 10 instead of 26 (normal). My task manager says it constantly uses 0.4% of my memory (16GB RAM), the use doesn't increase so probably there is no memory leak (btw: the cpu usage is a lot though: 20% for a game of only 500 lines of code (I have Ryzen 5)).

Also: the falling fps drops more drastically: in the beginning if I fall the fps is the same as walking, but after a while it's only 10 even tho the walking fps is 17 or so. Does anyone have an idea what could be making my game slower and slower over time, and especially the falling (like: is there something like a memory leak that could be causing this, even tho the memory/processor usages don't increase)?

This is the falling code (inside the player class, this function gets called every tick if the player is not jumping):

```
def fall(self, tiles):
    if not self.collision_from_below:
        self.y_velocity += 1
        for tile in tiles:
            if tile.top <= self.top + (self.y_velocity ** 2)/2 and tile.top >= self.top and self.right >= tile.left and self.right <= tile.right or tile.top <= self.top + (self.y_velocity ** 2)/2 and tile.top >= self.top and self.left >= tile.left and self.left <= tile.right:
                self.bottom = tile.top
                self.y_velocity = 0
        self.y += (self.y_velocity ** 2)/2
    else:
        self.y_velocity = 0
```

Edit: after testing with task manager again, I saw that the cpu usage does increase, but it stops increasing at around 20% (it starts at 1% and quickly increases (+/-1% per second)

Comment: It is very likely that over time you add more and more objects to a container (list or `pygame.sprite.Group`) but never remove them. The more objects are in the container the slower the game becomes. Do you shoot bullets, but do not remove them when they are outside the window bounds?  Do you spawn enemies and constantly increase the number of enemies? Or do you create other objects over time?

Comment: *"This is the falling code:"* - No, it is not. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @Rabbid76, that could indeed be the problem, as the cpu usage does increase... My player can throw axes but I delete them when they hit and I tested the fps without throwing any, and the enemies are loaded from a level file (.json) and put inside a list, but they're also deleted when they die and the fps is the same in a map without enemies, but maybe I have some other lists that keep getting bigger...

Comment: `print(len(your_list))` may help to find the problem

Comment: I made the falling code more understandable (I think?), the long line of code just looks if the player is going to go through a block, and then he instead of going down with the full speed, he falls right on top of the floor tiles (otherwise, due to the changing y velocity  the player would fall into a tile).

Comment: This code is not the problem. This code only slows down when the number of tiles increases. You are looking for the problem in the wrong place.

Comment: I think I found it, there is a list where I told it to append '0' every tick (idk why, probably as a place holder), so every tick the list got longer and longer. @Rabbid76, thanks so much for the help...

Comment: I even found another list increasing it's length by 85 every tick, now the problem is really solved. (cpu usage is now 1-1.2%)

Comment: BTW: The code is recomputing `(self.y_velocity ** 2)/2` many times inside the `for tile` loop.  But this value is constant within the loop.  It would be better calculated once outside the loop and re-used.

Answer (score 0):

It is very likely that over time you add more and more objects to a container (list or `pygame.sprite.Group`) but never remove them. The more objects are in the container the slower the game becomes. Do you shoot bullets, but do not remove them when they are outside the window bounds? Do you spawn enemies and constantly increase the number of enemies? Or do you create other objects over time?